# Excel: Add comment author using vba

Tags: excel, comments, vba

When I add comments to a cell manually (using the insert comment command) the text is preceded by my username in bold font.

Is it possible to replicate this characteristic for comments created in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) using `Range.AddComment()` (for whichever user is running the macro) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the logged in user name (with the user name in bold) like so - this example for cell A1:

```
Sub EasyTest()
Dim shCmt As Comment
On Error Resume Next
Set shCmt = [a1].Comment
On Error GoTo 0
If shCmt Is Nothing Then
Set shCmt = [a1].AddComment
shCmt.Text Text:=Environ$("UserName") & Chr(10) & "TestMe"
shCmt.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, Len(Environ$("UserName"))).Font.Bold = True
Else
MsgBox "cell already has a comment"
End If
End Sub
```